# How to add device to the Adhoc Distribution profile

Tags: ios, testflight

I am attempting to install a App via Test Flight

When I click on the URL provided by Test Flight I get a "This build is not available for this device"

I suspect that this is because on my iOS Provisioning portal - Under the Distribution Profile the Device I am attempting to install is not listed

Is this assumption correct - If correct how does one add a device to the Distribution Provision Profile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add the device to your developer portal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/AddingaDeviceIDtoYourDevelopmentTeam/AddingaDeviceIDtoYourDevelopmentTeam.html)

Then you will need to create/modify the profile, making sure your device is included in the list

[Creating a Distribution Provisioning Profile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011211-CH3-SW1)

Comment: After adding the device to the portal and then adding the device to the Profile - 


Do I then have to rebuild the IPA and upload it again to Testflight and then download it to the recently added device.


Does this have to be done for every added device - I was under the impression that all this could be done from Testflight.   What value does testflight offer other than proving a URL to access the IPA file

Comment: TestFlight actually lets you just upload the modified profile if you want to. To do this go to your build in TestFlight > Permissions > Update Profile. From there you can upload the modified profile and it will do the rest of the work for you. Generally though yes, you would need to rebuild the IPA as the profile is packaged with it. TestFlight just does some "magic" to prevent the need to do this.